# Simulating Enter in Bash Script on CentOS 6 Minimal

Tags: linux, bash, enter

Right now I am using:

```
echo -ne '\n' | alternatives --config java
```

For

```
Enter to keep the current selection, or type selection number:
```

I know there are probably many ways to do this. I am looking for the correct way to perform this action. I honestly don't even know if I'm doing it right.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the context in which you are needing to "simulate pressing enter". I get that you have some menu displayed and that you want the key press of `[Enter]` to preserve the current selection, but honestly, without seeing a reasonable block of code that shows how the selection is taking place, I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to help.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin See Step #2   http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/

Comment: Yes, that was what I was picturing, but there is no way to know what is going on the in loop structure creating the java-alternative menu or how the keyboard input is being interpreted. Do you have a link to the actual script that's running? That script was discontinued on suse several releases ago.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Unfortunately I do not.

Comment: I think I still have an 11.0 box running as a fax-server. I'll take a look to see if it has it. If I find it, I'll see if I can't add the code here. I'm curious as to the context.

Comment: Just `echo` will output a single newline just fine; no need for the clumsy `-ne '\n'` which isn't portable anyway.  If you want portable and explicit, try `printf '\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you could use something less interactive.

```
alternatives --set java /your/favorite/version
```

should work.
Or you can use 'expect' command to emulate user input.